# Quartz triggered jobs in ERROR state no longer calls execute

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We have a noticed a few of our triggered jobs go into ERROR state from time to time.
[image]
While in this state `execute` is no longer called!  **Is there any configuration on quartz to control this behavior?  I would prefer for it to just keep retrying/triggering the job**.

We are still unsure what initially causes the ERROR state.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799452/530933) seems to imply it is because the pod assigned to the job is lost/deleted/etc; however I don't think that's how triggers work, that seems to be more affiliated with scheduling jobs.  To troubleshoot we have implemented the trigger listener:

```
public class QuartzJobListener implements TriggerListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzJobListener.class);

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        LOGGER.info("Job executing via trigger: " + trigger.getJobKey());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        LOGGER.info("Job execution vetoed: " + trigger.getJobKey());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
        LOGGER.info("Job trigger misfired: " + trigger.getJobKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
        LOGGER.info("Job trigger completed: " + trigger.getJobKey());
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "QuartzJobListener";
    }
}
```

But there is no error case here making it even harder to detect when we initially get into ERROR state and why.

Here is how we create our triggered jobs:

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "tickets.background.job", name = "deliver-tickets.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    JobDescription deliverTicketsJobDescription() {
        final long now = metrics ? System.currentTimeMillis() : 0;
        JobDescription jobDescription =  JobDescriptionBuilder.builder()
                .triggerType(TriggerType.CRON)
                .jobClass(DeliverTicketsJob.class)
                .cronExpression(deliverTicketsCron)
                .jobGroupId(jobGroupId)
                .jobId("deliverTickets")
                .build();
        if (metrics) {
            LOGGER.debug("METRIC: deliverTicketsJobDescription ~ duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms");
        }
        return jobDescription;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper exception handling in your job implementation? Quartz expects
you to throw *JobExecutionException* in error case and the class has flags to control the retry behavior of the job, I think *setRefireImmediately* is what you are looking for.

See also:

- https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/Job.html
- https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionException.html